# Import/Export from iPhone app for sharing data objects from core data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I'm developing an app with a feature that needs to import and export from the apps coreData. 
I want a feature that allows users to export files (to a custom format, i.e. XML with another file ending *.myformat) to share with other users. If the other user does not have the app it would be preferred if him/her were redirected to the appstore page of my app (Is this possible without to much hassle).

Could you provide some links or clues on how to implement this feature.

button press-> 
export data objects, with parent X from core data->
share on facebook/twitter/mail->
new user gets file taps it and the data object X is imported to the new user's instance of the app.

Comment: May I suggest looking at 'Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers Reference' by Apple.[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: [Ray has tried it all](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app)